# Error when expo start in react native application (Stylesheet)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm making a react native application and there is an error that is making me sick.

Could anyone help me?

The error is shown below.

[image: First error]

[image: Second error]

Dependencies:

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an error in case, it should be `StyleSheet` and not `Stylesheet`